# Change Rail Model attribute's label

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

This is my model:

```
class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  belongs_to :user, optional: true
  has_many :comments

  field :title, type: String
  field :body, type: String

  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :body, presence: true

end
```

When I get a validation error on the body field I get "Body can't be blank" and I want to change this to "Content Can't be blank" in the model. How do I change the field label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that in `config/locales/en.yml`, by overriding the attributes' label of a model:

```
en:
...
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      post:
        body: 'Content'
```

For `Mongoid`, replace `activerecord` above with `mongoid`. If that doesn't work try:

```
en:
  mongoid:
    attributes:
      body: 'Content'
```

This is called as translation process for I18n. With this, you can basically override the naming etc for any model (say, User --> Customer), attributes, error messages etc. On top of it, you can also have other files like `es-CO.yml`, to target translation on other languages out-of-the-box.

You can read more about [translation here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models).

Comment: Replace `activerecord` above with `mongoid`.

Comment: @kiddorails Shouldn't there be a level `post` between `attributes` and `body` as in the first example on active record? Or would this change all body attributes in all models?

Answer (score 0):

Add this in `config/locales/en.yml`

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      post:
        body: "Content"
```

This will change the attribute name while giving errors

Comment: `body` needs to be "Content" and not 'Post'.